# String matching using preg_match() in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string something like this

```
$str="syx.ypzd [xys.ypd] yup";
```

I am trying to get the value inside `[ ]` .

I have a code something like this

```
preg_match('[xys.ypd]', $str, $Fdesc);
echo $Fdesc[1];
```

But this is not working

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You need to put more effort into solving your problems. For now, [see this](http://php-regex.blogspot.com/search/label/Regular%20Expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right syntax :

```
/\[(.*)\]/
```

This one will match what is between `[` and `]`.

- `/` the start of the regex
- `\[` matches the `[`
- `(.*)` matches any number of characters (the parenthesis "capture" this part so you will get it in the results)
- `\]` matches the `]`
- `/` the end of the regex

The code :

```
preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $code, $Fdesc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that works

```
  $str="syx.ypzd [xys.ypd] yup";
  preg_match('[xys.ypd]', $str, $Fdesc);
  print_r($Fdesc);
```

Output:

Array
(
    [0] => xys.ypd
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
preg_match('\[(.*)\]', $code, $Fdesc);
echo $Fdesc[1];
```

Comment: And where is the difference to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29747093/3933332 ?

Comment: Didn't see that one. You are right.